# Does ActiveMQ support clusturing to scale MQTT to multiple brokers?

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

I am very new to MQTT and ActiveMQ. I wanted to know whether we are able to scale ActiveMQ via clustering for MQTT. I was looking for an open-source MQTT broker which can scale horizontally to have lots of connected clients (100k+).

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Comment: hi @JustinBertram, thanks a lot for answering the question. The docs of ActiveMQ is actually a bit confusing. I couldn't see many references to MQTT being supported by Artemis clustering. This is supported, right?. I'm pretty new to this. Thanks

Comment: Clustering is protocol agnostic so all protocols are supported with clustering.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ can scale via what's called a [network of brokers](https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers).

However, if you want the best performance I would recommend taking a look at [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://%20http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/), the next generation ActiveMQ broker. It also supports [clustering](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html), and it's built on a high performance, non-blocking architecture. Here is a [3rd party benchmark](https://softwaremill.com/mqperf/) that compares the performance potential of a handful of message brokers. As you can see, ActiveMQ Artemis performs very well, especially compared to its competitors.

To be clear, clustering is protocol agnostic so all protocols are supported with clustering.

Comment: Do the network of Mqtt brokers share state in this setup? For example, if a persistent client disconnects and connects to another broker in the same network, are the subscriptions carried forward?

Comment: You should create a new question for this.

Comment: You mentioned "clustering is protocol agnostic so all protocols are supported with clustering." I am trying to get clarification on that comment. Clustering cannot be just be a bunch of brokers in a network, they have to share the state too. The state will be specific to the `implementation` of the protocol, in this case MQTT topic mapping, routes, etc.

Comment: That's fair enough, but this question has already been marked as answered so you should create a new one.